# How to connect to a database if the password or username given by the user in SQLAlchemy's connection string contains an @,: or / symbol

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, character-encoding, fastapi, connection-string

I am taking a connection string from user input and am getting an error if the given string contains @,/,:, etc. So, how can I resolve it?

Example:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

connection_string = "mssql+pymssql://demo:Testing@123@Server-name"  # suppose this type of input given by the user.
engine = create_engine(connection_string)
print(engine.connect())
```

In the example above the password is "Testing@123" but sqlalchemy takes "Testing" as the password and "123@Server-name" as the server name.

I know about quote_plus but I think we need password separately and then we can do something like this: "mssql+pymssql://demo:%s@Server-name" % quote_plus("Testing@123")
But I'm taking the full connection string as input so, anyone have any idea how I can handle it dynamically?